# Pyspark SQL expression versus when() as a case statement

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I create a field called v1 in a previous query. Then I try to create a new derived field from it.

One method works, the other doesnt. I dont understand, I expected they are equivalent.

This works:

```
df = df.withColumn("outcome",expr("case when v1 = 0 then 1 when v1 > 0 then 2 else 0 end"))
```

This fails:

```
df = df.withColumn("outcome", F.when(F.col("v1") == 0, 1)
      .F.when(F.col("v1") >0, 2)
      .otherwise(0))
```

with error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o520.when.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: when() can only be applied on a Column previously generated by when() function
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have called `when` from `pyspark.sql.functions` or `F`, You need to chain your `when` conditions (like `F.when().when().when().otherwise()`), you don't need to call it from `F` again.

Just change your code to :

```
df = df.withColumn("outcome", F.when(F.col("v1") == 0, 1)
      .when(F.col("v1") >0, 2)
      .otherwise(0))
```

Comment: You don't need to call 'F.' again each time you call 'when'?

Comment: You've called it once, so you just need to chain them. `F.when().when().when().otherwise()`